# Google Maps direction service not working properly for custom Infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have to create Google Maps direction service From / To points and it should work both - from map clicks From /To and using autocomplete text boxes where user has to fill in From /To destinations and both to be marked as markers on the map. 
Finally it will draw route on the map. 
Using separately both work, for example if I click from / to it will draw the route, but for some reason gets wrong custom Infowindow. 
How it is supposed to work:
When you click on map for first time it should create and OPEN custom Infowindow "From address".
When you click on map for second time it should create and OPEN custom Infowindow "To address".

The problems with the Infowindow are as following:

1. Onclick, It only shows Infowindow "From address".
2. When you click on the map for a second time and the route is draw both markers are not showing the custom Infowindows OPENED and if you click on the marker you will discover that the custom Infowindows are missing.

I have prepared a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thecore/pv8o30L4/73/) where you can see nearly working DEMO :)

Please excuse me if the code looks mess, but I had to remove a lot of code in order to reproduce the problem.

Please help me to fix the above problems

```js
var map;
var marker; // move marker definition into the global scope
var infowindow;
var uniqueId = 1;
var infoWindowcontent;
var markers = [];
function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer) {
//console.log(marker);
  directionsService.route({
      origin: {
        query: document.getElementById('departure_address').value
      },
      destination: {
        query: document.getElementById('arrival_address').value
      },
      travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    },
    function(response, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        var point = response.routes[0].legs[0];
        //console.log(point);
        directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
  
   createMarker(response.routes[0].legs[0].start_location, "A", "start marker", map, infowindow);
  var lastLeg = response.routes[0].legs.length - 1;
  createMarker(response.routes[0].legs[lastLeg].end_location, "B", "end marker", map, infowindow);
  //infowindow.open(map,marker);
        if (marker && marker.setMap) // hide click marker when directions displayed
          marker.setMap(null);
      } else {
        alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
    });
}

function initMap_mobile() {
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mobilemap'), {
    mapTypeControl: false,
    center: {
 lat: 42.700000762939, 
 lng: 23.333299636841
    },
    zoom: 13
  });
  directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
  //var infowindow;

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({
      'latLng': new google.maps.LatLng(event.latLng.lat(), event.latLng.lng())
    }, function(results, status) {
      //otherwise clicks twice
      set_lat_long(event.latLng.lat(), event.latLng.lng(), results[0].formatted_address, directionsService, directionsRenderer);
      
    //alert(uniqueId);
   if(uniqueId == 1){
   label = 'From Address';
   infoWindowcontent = '<div class="ib infobox"><label style="font-weight:bold;text-transform: uppercase;">From Address:</label><hr><br/>'+results[0].formatted_address+'<br /><br /><button class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-sm" onclick = "clear_dep();" value = "delete">Delete</button><br/></div>';
   }
   if(uniqueId == 2){
   label = 'To Address';
   infoWindowcontent = '<div class="ib infobox"><label style="font-weight:bold;text-transform: uppercase;">To Address:</label><hr><br/>'+results[0].formatted_address+'<br /><br /><button class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-sm" onclick = "clear_arr();" value = "delete">Delete</button><br/></div>';
   }
   if (marker == null) {
   console.log(event.latLng);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: event.latLng,
  draggable: true,
  label: {
   text: label,
   color: '#a2003b'
  },
  
  animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
  map: map
        });
  
  
  marker.id = uniqueId;
      }else {
        marker.setPosition(event.latLng);
      }
   
   
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: infoWindowcontent
   });
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  uniqueId++;

   //Add marker to the array.
      markers.push(marker);
    });
  });
}



function createMarker(location, label, content, map, id) {
//console.log(location.lat);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
   // label: label,
    title: label,
 id: id,
 icon: {
    url: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal4/icon31.png',
    // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels high.
    // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at (0, 32).
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
  },
    map: map
  });
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
   content: content,
   maxWidth: 350
});
 infowindow.setContent(content);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
 
 //console.log(marker);
 markers.push(marker);
 
}

function set_lat_long(lat, lng, address, directionsService, directionsRenderer) {
  var dep_lat = $('#dep_lat').val();
  var dep_lng = $('#dep_lng').val();
  var arr_lat = $('#arr_lat').val();
  var arr_lng = $('#arr_lng').val();

  if (isEmpty(dep_lat) || isEmpty(dep_lng)) {
    //alert(dep_lat);
    $('#dep_lat').val(lat);
    $('#dep_lng').val(lng);
    $('#departure_address').val(address);
    $('#clear_dep').show();
  } else {
    if (isEmpty(arr_lat) || isEmpty(arr_lng)) {
      $('#arr_lat').val(lat);
      $('#arr_lng').val(lng);
      $('#arrival_address').val(address);
      $('#clear_arr,.arrival_address').show();
    }
  }

  if (!isEmpty($('#dep_lat').val()) && !isEmpty($('#dep_lng').val()) && !isEmpty($('#arr_lat').val()) && !isEmpty($('#arr_lng').val())) calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer);
}

function isEmpty(value) {
  return (value == null || value.length === 0);
}
initMap_mobile();
```

```css
#mobilemap {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px #ddd;
}
input{margin:5px;}
.clear {

    cursor: pointer;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDdEHqLflmCXJ8MzV8tfJGVsvy2GYeQ7lg&libraries=places&callback=initMap_mobile" async defer></script>

<div class="cell-xs-12 mobw100 npr">
<div id="mode-selector" class="controls">Driving Mode selector
<input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-driving" checked="checked" />  
</div>
  <div class="form-group text-right">
    <label for="departure_address" class="form-label">From</label>
    <input maxlength="100" id="departure_address" placeholder="From address" type="text" name="departure_address" class="controls form-control form-control-gray-base dybck" value="" style="background: rgb(255, 236, 236) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;" autocomplete="off">
<small id="clear_dep" onclick="clear_dep();" class="ib w100 tar clear" style="display: inline;">Clear address</small>
    <input type="hidden" name="dep_lat" id="dep_lat" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="dep_lng" id="dep_lng" value="">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="cell-xs-12 offset-top-20 mobw100 npr he arrival_address">
  <div class="form-group text-right">
    <label for="arrival_address" class="form-label">To</label>
    <input maxlength="100" id="arrival_address" placeholder="To address" type="text" name="arrival_address" class="controls form-control form-control-gray-base" value="" autocomplete="off">
<small id="clear_arr" onclick="clear_arr();" class="ib w100 tar clear" style="display: inline;">Clear address</small>
    <input type="hidden" name="arr_lat" id="arr_lat" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="arr_lng" id="arr_lng" value="">
  </div>
  
  <div class="cell-xs-12 offset-top-20 mobw100 npr he tal date date_hide">
                         <div class="form-group ib w50 vat">
                          <label for="date" class="form-label">Date</label>
                          <input readonly id="date" data-time-picker="date" type="text" name="travel_date" class="form-control form-control-gray-base dates" value="2019-09-10"/>
                        </div>
   <div class="cell-xs-12 offset-top-20 mobw100 npr he tal pax_adults mt10" style="display: block;">
<div class="form-group ib w50 ">
   <label for="pax_adults" class="form-label fs11">Pax N</label>
   <input min="1" id="pax_adults" type="number" name="pax_adults" class="p5 form-control form-control-gray-base" value="" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">
 </div>
</div> 

<div class="cell-xs-12 offset-top-20 npr he hm tal colback mt10" style="display: block;">
      <div class="form-group nmb ib w100 tac"><h6 id="show_more" class="option-heading">Travel info</h6><hr></div>
    
    <div class="form-group nmb ib w100 tac mtb10 option-content is-hidden">
    <div class="form-group nmb ib w100 tac mtb10">
    <div class="form-group nmb ib w50 tac">
      <label for="travel_distance" class="form-label">Distance</label>
      <input readonly="" type="text" name="travel_distance" id="travel_distance" value="">
       </div>
      <div class="form-group nmb ib w50 tac">
    <label for="travel_time" class="form-label">Travel duration</label>
      <input readonly="" type="hidden" name="normal_travel_time" id="normal_travel_time" value="">
      <input readonly="" type="text" name="travel_time" id="travel_time" value="">
       </div>
       </div>
      
      <div class="form-group nmb ib w100 tac mtb10">
      <label for="travel_price" class="form-label">Travel price USD</label>
      <input readonly="" class="ib" type="text" name="travel_price" id="travel_price" value=""> 
       </div>
    <hr>
       </div>    
    
      </div>
</div>
<div id="mobilemap"></div>
```

Thank you in advance for your time
[image]

Comment: My fiddle didn't fix the InfoWindows, just the error on "Delete"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. your global `map` variable is not initialized.  You need to either pass it into the `createMarker` function (it is available from `directionRenderer.getMap()`) or initialize the global `map` variable (by removing the `var` in the line that initializes the map).
2. you need to suppress the markers created by the directions renderer (`var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({suppressMarkers: true});`)

[image: screenshot of route with custom markers]

```js
var marker; // move marker definition into the global scope
var infowindow;
var uniqueId = 1;
var infoWindowcontent;
var markers = [];

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer) {
  directionsService.route({
      origin: {
        query: document.getElementById('departure_address').value
      },
      destination: {
        query: document.getElementById('arrival_address').value
      },
      travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    },
    function(response, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        var point = response.routes[0].legs[0];
        directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);

        createMarker(response.routes[0].legs[0].start_location, "A", "start marker", directionsRenderer.getMap(), infowindow);
        var lastLeg = response.routes[0].legs.length - 1;
        createMarker(response.routes[0].legs[lastLeg].end_location, "B", "end marker", directionsRenderer.getMap(), infowindow);
        if (marker && marker.setMap) // hide click marker when directions displayed
          marker.setMap(null);
      } else {
        alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
    });
}

function initMap_mobile() {
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    suppressMarkers: true
  });
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mobilemap'), {
    mapTypeControl: false,
    center: {
      lat: 42.700000762939,
      lng: 23.333299636841
    },
    zoom: 13
  });
  directionsRenderer.setMap(map);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({
      'latLng': new google.maps.LatLng(event.latLng.lat(), event.latLng.lng())
    }, function(results, status) {
      //otherwise clicks twice
      set_lat_long(event.latLng.lat(), event.latLng.lng(), results[0].formatted_address, directionsService, directionsRenderer);

      if (uniqueId == 1) {
        label = 'From Address';
        infoWindowcontent = '<div class="ib infobox"><label style="font-weight:bold;text-transform: uppercase;">From Address:</label><hr><br/>' + results[0].formatted_address + '<br /><br /><button class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-sm" onclick = "clear_dep();" value = "delete">Delete</button><br/></div>';
      }
      if (uniqueId == 2) {
        label = 'To Address';
        infoWindowcontent = '<div class="ib infobox"><label style="font-weight:bold;text-transform: uppercase;">To Address:</label><hr><br/>' + results[0].formatted_address + '<br /><br /><button class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-sm" onclick = "clear_arr();" value = "delete">Delete</button><br/></div>';
      }
      if (marker == null) {
        console.log(event.latLng);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: event.latLng,
          draggable: true,
          label: {
            text: label,
            color: '#a2003b'
          },

          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          map: map
        });
        marker.id = uniqueId;
      } else {
        marker.setPosition(event.latLng);
      }
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: infoWindowcontent
      });
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
      uniqueId++;

      //Add marker to the array.
      markers.push(marker);
    });
  });
}

function createMarker(location, label, content, map, id) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    title: label,
    id: id,
    icon: {
      url: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal4/icon31.png',
      // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels high.
      // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at (0, 32).
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
    },
    map: map
  });
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: content,
    maxWidth: 350
  });
  infowindow.setContent(content);
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
  markers.push(marker);
}

function set_lat_long(lat, lng, address, directionsService, directionsRenderer) {
  var dep_lat = $('#dep_lat').val();
  var dep_lng = $('#dep_lng').val();
  var arr_lat = $('#arr_lat').val();
  var arr_lng = $('#arr_lng').val();

  if (isEmpty(dep_lat) || isEmpty(dep_lng)) {
    //alert(dep_lat);
    $('#dep_lat').val(lat);
    $('#dep_lng').val(lng);
    $('#departure_address').val(address);
    $('#clear_dep').show();
  } else {
    if (isEmpty(arr_lat) || isEmpty(arr_lng)) {
      $('#arr_lat').val(lat);
      $('#arr_lng').val(lng);
      $('#arrival_address').val(address);
      $('#clear_arr,.arrival_address').show();
    }
  }

  if (!isEmpty($('#dep_lat').val()) && !isEmpty($('#dep_lng').val()) && !isEmpty($('#arr_lat').val()) && !isEmpty($('#arr_lng').val())) calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer);
}

function isEmpty(value) {
  return (value == null || value.length === 0);
}
initMap_mobile();
```

```css
#mobilemap {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px #ddd;
}

input {
  margin: 5px;
}

.clear {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=initMap_mobile" async defer></script>

<div class="cell-xs-12 mobw100 npr">
  <div id="mode-selector" class="controls">Driving Mode selector
    <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-driving" checked="checked" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group text-right">
    <label for="departure_address" class="form-label">From</label>
    <input maxlength="100" id="departure_address" placeholder="From address" type="text" name="departure_address" class="controls form-control form-control-gray-base dybck" value="" style="background: rgb(255, 236, 236) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;" autocomplete="off">
    <small id="clear_dep" onclick="clear_dep();" class="ib w100 tar clear" style="display: inline;">Clear address</small>
    <input type="hidden" name="dep_lat" id="dep_lat" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="dep_lng" id="dep_lng" value="">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="cell-xs-12 offset-top-20 mobw100 npr he arrival_address">
  <div class="form-group text-right">
    <label for="arrival_address" class="form-label">To</label>
    <input maxlength="100" id="arrival_address" placeholder="To address" type="text" name="arrival_address" class="controls form-control form-control-gray-base" value="" autocomplete="off">
    <small id="clear_arr" onclick="clear_arr();" class="ib w100 tar clear" style="display: inline;">Clear address</small>
    <input type="hidden" name="arr_lat" id="arr_lat" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="arr_lng" id="arr_lng" value="">
  </div>

  <div class="cell-xs-12 offset-top-20 mobw100 npr he tal date date_hide">
    <div class="form-group ib w50 vat">
      <label for="date" class="form-label">Date</label>
      <input readonly id="date" data-time-picker="date" type="text" name="travel_date" class="form-control form-control-gray-base dates" value="2019-09-10" />
    </div>
    <div class="cell-xs-12 offset-top-20 mobw100 npr he tal pax_adults mt10" style="display: block;">
      <div class="form-group ib w50 ">
        <label for="pax_adults" class="form-label fs11">Pax N</label>
        <input min="1" id="pax_adults" type="number" name="pax_adults" class="p5 form-control form-control-gray-base" value="" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="cell-xs-12 offset-top-20 npr he hm tal colback mt10" style="display: block;">
      <div class="form-group nmb ib w100 tac">
        <h6 id="show_more" class="option-heading">Travel info</h6>
        <hr>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group nmb ib w100 tac mtb10 option-content is-hidden">
        <div class="form-group nmb ib w100 tac mtb10">
          <div class="form-group nmb ib w50 tac">
            <label for="travel_distance" class="form-label">Distance</label>
            <input readonly="" type="text" name="travel_distance" id="travel_distance" value="">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group nmb ib w50 tac">
            <label for="travel_time" class="form-label">Travel duration</label>
            <input readonly="" type="hidden" name="normal_travel_time" id="normal_travel_time" value="">
            <input readonly="" type="text" name="travel_time" id="travel_time" value="">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group nmb ib w100 tac mtb10">
          <label for="travel_price" class="form-label">Travel price USD</label>
          <input readonly="" class="ib" type="text" name="travel_price" id="travel_price" value="">
        </div>
        <hr>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="mobilemap"></div>
```

Comment: No infowindows are shown on the snippet after the route is displayed. Neither on marker click or default opened - was it supposed to work this way?

Comment: Your `createMarker``function doesn't create an `InfoWindow` or add the click event handler to open it.

Comment: probably you see an outdated function createmarker, I am updating above the final one..

Comment: The code in my answer uses the one that existed in your question when you asked it.

Comment: Replacing the `createMarker` function in the code in my answer, gives custom markers and open InfoWindows in my testing ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/d3w8zv2h/))